# Conceptual Thing - Consume Events From Remote Machine

Tags: c#, events, wmi

I have to consume permanent a specific event from remote machine's eventlog.
I cannot implement a pull method to receive the event (too much network traffic).

I've read about WMI temporary event subscription and WMI permanent event subscription. But permanent event subscription isn't implemented in System.Management Namespace.

Are there any other possibilities to consume permanent events from remote machine's eventlog without installing something on remote machine (programmatically!)?

Comment: Please don't add " (C#)" and such to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement some simple program on the remote machine that will watch the event log and "push" interesting events to the monitoring machine via SOAP service, named pipe, or some sockets-based comm package of your own design. That would probably be the easiest way, assuming you have control of the remote machine. That way, the "polling" that simply has to be done at some level happens within the bounds of one machine, and just costs a few CPU cycles and data reads instead of constant network calls.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. There are too many remote machines. On the other side, we aren't allowed to install software on remote machines (for that purpose).

Comment: Fair enough. Have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28226/Creating-WMI-Permanent-Event-Subscriptions-Using-M; it says that not only is it possible to establish a permanent subscription using System.Management, you can also use MOF code embedded in a C# program to establish a permanent subscription from the subscribing computer.

Comment: Thanks. I've already read the article. But I didn't know, that I'm able to embed MOF code in a C# program. I have to test it.